# AngularJs Directives: nested ng-class is failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I'm facing a strange issue with AngularJs Directive when I need to have nested ng-class. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/alansouzati/9suhcmkd/) is a JSFiddle that shows the problem with an hypothetical situation.

**HTML**

```
<div in-directive ng-class="{ 'testing1': 1 == 1 }"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('inDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div ng-class="{ \'testing\': 1 == 1 }">Hi</div>'
    };
});
```

**AngularJS Error**

Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 25 of the expression [{ 'testing11': 1 == 1 } { 'testing': 1 == 1 }] starting at [{ 'testing': 1 == 1 }].

```
[{ 'testing11': 1 == 1 } { 'testing': 1 == 1 }]
```

This is an invalid JSON. Am I doing something wrong here? Currently, the work-around that I did was to move the ng-class to a upper div element. But this is clearly not desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This similar issue has already been reported here [#8159 Directive with 'replace: true' and template](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8159).

And AngularJS team has decided not to support a complex attribute merging when using a directive with `template/templateUrl` and `replace` flag set to true.

And this issue is one of the reason why they [are deprecating](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8195) the `replace` flag of directives.

You can also see a long discussion here [eec6394: deprecate `replace` directives](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/eec6394a342fb92fba5270eee11c83f1d895e9fb)

Comment: Great! Thanks @runTarm. I will avoid using replace as much I can from now on.

Answer (score 0):

When you have 2 element attributes like that, one in the element and one in the template, angular concatenates the strings, resulting in an invalid expression.

If you look in the HTML in your fiddle, this is what the element becomes:

`<div ng-class="{ 'testing1': 1 == 1 } { 'testing': 1 == 1 }" in-directive="">Hi</div>`

Comment: this I could notice. But do you think this is the expected behavior?

Comment: @AlanSouza of course, why wouldn't it be? it's just a string, and it gets concatenated before it gets eval'd by angular. That's how `template` works.

Comment: I understand your point. But if replace=true is supported I would expect AngularJS to handle merging scenarios for me. They will deprecate replace attribute because of that.